# Is $\log(n-1) \in \Omega(\log(n))$?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

I saw this question [Can I simplify log(n+1) before showing that it is in O(log n)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54157/can-i-simplify-logn1-before-showing-that-it-is-in-olog-n) and wanted to know if a similar situation was also true.

Namely, is $\log(n-1) \in \Omega(\log(n))$?

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, $\log(n+1) \in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$. That means that $\log n \in \Omega(\log( n + 1))$. Now you can change $n$ with $n-1$ and have your answer.

To be more precise, $\log(\alpha n^{\beta} + \gamma) \in \Theta(\log n)$ for any $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Hope Your  $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ doesn't contain $\alpha=0$, as then we have constant on left side.

Comment: Sorry, I am using French notations, as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Vocabulary_and_notation
It indeed means "any positive real number not zero". I modified my answer, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you! @Nathaniel

Answer (score 2):

Having $n-1 \gt \sqrt{n}$, when $n \gt 3$ we can write
$$\log (n-1) \gt \log \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{2}\log n$$
So, taking $N=3$ and $C=\frac{1}{2}\gt 0$ we fulfilled definition for $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you! @zkutch